# sshd_config AllowUsers Should Root Be Allowed?

Tags: openssh, sshd

I am asking here as i do not want to get locked out of my server.

I do not want to allow root login to ssh, however if a user enters a "su" command i want them to be able to become root. So do i include root on the "AllowUsers" part of sshd_config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AllowUsers` in `sshd_config` only controls who can log in via ssh, not what they can do once they are logged in. `su` and `sudo` (et al) will still continue to function as you would expect.

You probably also want to look at the `PermitRootLogin` directive.

Comment: `PermitRootLogin` is without effect if the `AllowUsers` directive is used. The later takes precedence, and if `root` is not listed explicitly, `root` is not allowed to log in.

Comment: @DanielAndersson - Exactly, which is why I'm mentioning it.

Comment: -1 you didn't mention that, you may have even given the impression that he should use both. Which is why Daniel's comment was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable root logins with a password, but still allow it with public keys. And for other users who can login with a password, you can limit it to a specific list of users.

```
# Allow only root, and 2 other users
AllowUsers root user1 user4

# But root cannot use password and must have a key for SSH instead
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password

# Other users can use a password. This is the default:
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```